# Does O(N(logN)^4) grow faster than O(N^3)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Does a O(N(logN)^4) function grow faster than O(N^3)? I can't really understand it much and can't define which grows faster.

Comment: Creating some graphs should help you guess the answer.  Then you can try to prove it.  Your calculus skills might be useful.

Comment: [chart](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2C+x+*+%28logx%29%5E4&assumption=%7B%22FunClash%22%2C+%22log%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Log10%22%7D)

Answer (score 2):

`O(N(logN)^4) < O(N^3)`

The rule to compare two `O` notation is to to the ratio and to see, if `n` goes to infinity, where the ratio goes.

In our example: `N(logN)^4/N^3 = log(N)^4/N^2 -> 0` so near infinity you will have `N(logN)^4/N^3 < 1 ~ N(logN)^4 < N^3`. This can be translated to `O(N(logN)^4) < O(N^3)`

Comment: @JamoliddinNosirov please do use Lulupointu methodology so you understand how to compare, but in general you can almost always assume anything with LogN in it will be less than any exponential function. Log curves approach 1 into infinity - but never reach - the values before and after (even exponentials) simply add to '1'  

I'm no mathematician so there are probably places where there exceptions, but  in *general* this is going to be the case

Comment: Log does not approach 1 towards infinity. Logs goes to infinity when its argument goes to infinity. However it is try that log is "weaker" than any polynomial (so also exponential) function, as it can easily be proved by studying `log(x)^a/x^b`. You realize that  `log(x)^a/x^b < 1` for a certain value, which means that `log(x)^a/x^(c) < 1/x^e` (with b=c-e, e being as small as needed for b to remain positive) which goes to 0 towards infinity, proving what we need.

Comment: this is a fair point to my overly broad statement! And a reminder that my math classes were a long time ago.